# In a setuid root program, how to check that the current user (that root is doing the work for) owns a file?

Tags: linux, permissions, setuid

The use case is a mount tool, I want to restrict mounting (a `unionfs(r+x dir, squashfs)` ) to files owned by the caller.

I know about fusefs, But I'd like to use overlayfs and squashfs in the kernel.

Comment: Don't put your question into the headline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as you haven't called `setuid()` or `setreuid()` yet, you can use `getuid()` to get the user ID of the user that executed your program. Once you've done that, you can use `stat()` to get the owner of a file.

Alternatively, you can use the `access()` system call to check whether the user can read, write, and/or execute a specified path. `access()` uses the real user ID, not the effective user ID, so it will not use root's permissions to perform this access check.

In either case, take care that you do not introduce a time-of-check/time-of-use (TOCTOU) vulnerability in this check. Remember, the object pointed to by a path may change at any time, even while your application is running. Symbolic links are a particular hazard here!

Comment: Yeah, i think i may end up using fuse after all. This stuff is scary. I've read that it's better to isolate the root requiring operation in a subprogram and carefully veto its arguments, but that may introduce another window for TOCTOU in this case and really, i have no clue how to make certain such a minimal program can only get called by my 'blessed' one. It's sad that it's so impractical to use the more efficient filesystems in the kernel as a plain joe programmer for plain joe user.